# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts - communication packets

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm having issue connection to MySQL Server. I have a server from a hosting A. When I try to connect from localhost it always works fine. I publish my application (asp.net) to azure. Then, it shows the error:

```
    [MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +1155
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() +22
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +239
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() +11
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +287
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +93
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +65
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +627
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +359
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2() +55
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open() +253
```

I checked the mysqld.err and it says:

```
Got an error reading communication packets
```

So, I updated the max_allowed_packet from 100M to 500M. It worked for about 10 minutes (2 to 3 requests). Then it is showing the "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" again.

I also noticed a Warning in my MySQL log:

```
IP address 'azure-ip' could not be resolved: No such host is known.
```

Does anybody know what can be the problem?

Comment: MySQL client on azure uses a older connection protocol i think

Comment: My MySQL is in another hosting provider. I'm trying to access from an application hosted in Azure

Comment: It looks like the first time I connect from Azure, it works and open a PROCESS on MySQL. But, after a while the process time get too big (1000) and never closes. Then when I try to connect again it shows: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts